Searching for text in a column in google sheets, and determining if text exists in that range
I'm having a hard time finding a solution to what I think should be a relatively simply task. Please see attached example screenshot.
Screenshot of google sheet
What I want to do is:
I have a "database" in column B. column A is a number that a user inputs. I want to check if the user input exists in the database, and if it does, I simply want the column next to the database to say "Yes" or "No".
Columns D and E are my attempts at this.
VLookup works ok, but this is not the response I want. I want "Yes" or "No".
I tried an IF Statment, but I get an error "In Search Evaluatio, cannot find '5' within '1'.

Consider including a live example sheet, such as via using this tool.

Try this formula-
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A1,B:B)),"Yes","No")


Yes this is perfect!!! I could not figure it out. Thanks for your help!

@JustinVargas Glad to know it works! If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.
